# Setar valor em textview

Tags: android

Basicamente não estou conseguindo setar o valor no campo.

Estou fazendo assim, declarei as variaveis:

```
    Restaurante restaurante;

@ViewById
TextView nmRestaurante;

@ViewById
ImageView imgLogoRestaurante;

@ViewById
RatingBar ratingBar;

@ViewById
ListView lisComentarios;

@ViewById
LinearLayout lytEmptyComentarios;


List<Comentarios> lstComentarios;

GenericAdapter<Comentarios> adapter;
```

Depois o método `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comentarios);
    restaurante = Globales.getRestauranteAtual();
    View v = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    nmRestaurante = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nmRestaurante);
    imgLogoRestaurante = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogoRestaurante);
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    lisComentarios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisComentarios);
    lytEmptyComentarios = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytEmptyComentarios);

    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) v;
    toolbarTitle.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());

    nmRestaurante.setText(restaurante.getNomeRestaurante());
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(restaurante.getUrlImagem()).into(imgLogoRestaurante);

    ratingBar.setRating(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(restaurante
            .getMedia())));

    carregarComentarios(restaurante.getCodigoRestaurante());
}
```

No log não da erro algum, e mesmo assim os campos ficam brancos

Tenho certeza que esta tendo os dados
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Provavelmente `restaurante.getNomeRestaurante()` está retornando uma `String` vazia.. teria que ver aonde você carrega a entidade..

Comment: Utilizei o `break point` e vi que esta vindo, coloco na variavel restaurante aprti daqui `restaurante = Globales.getRestauranteAtual();
    restaurante = Globales.getRestauranteAtual();`

Comment: Talvez então a posição do  `TextView` não esteja aparecendo na View, ou está embaixo de algum outro componente... tenta "setar" um texto fixo no  `XML ` e apenas carregar o layout com  `setContentView ` e ver se aparece...

Comment: Quando seto no XML ele aparece normalmente, então não é nada tampando. esta muito estranho tudo isto...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que pode estar dando algum problema de você usar a annotation @ViewById e depois no código estar dando um findViewById.

Tente remover a annotation e nos diga o que aconteceu.

-- EDIT--

O erro acontecia pois ao utilizar a annotation de @ViewById, as views não estão instanciadas no método onCreate(), conforme documentação.

https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views

E como ele estava utilizando o método findViewById a annotation não estava tendo uso nenhum no código.

Para utilizar a annotation ele deveria utilizar o metodo @AfterViews, ex:

```
@AfterViews
void preencheDados() {
    //Preenche as view que estavam com @ViewById.
}
```